# TCP to virtual serial port with socat

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, serial, socat

I have a program (program 1) that has a TCP server listening on port 1234. I have confirmed that the server accepts connections and sends data with a utility str2str.

Program 2, on the same machine, needs this data but is configured to receive it via a serial port. I need to somehow forward the TCP data to (I believe) a virtual serial port.

I tried setting up the following virtual serial port pair, with the idea of streaming the TCP data to /dev/ttyVA00 so that program 2 can read the data from the paired ttyVB00:

```
sudo socat -d -d PTY,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyVA00 PTY,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyVB00
```

The link is set up however I'm really lost here, I tried the following but I can see no data coming in at ttyVB00:

```
sudo socat TCP:localhost:1234 pty,link=/dev/ttyVA00,raw,echo=0
```

Can someone please put me on the right track? Or better still, provide a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your second command doesn't open the existing /dev/ttyVA00 device; you're asking socat to create a *new* pty device at that location, overwriting the old one. (In TCP terms, it's not connecting to /dev/ttyVA00 – it's listening for incoming connections at /dev/ttyVA00.)

However, your second command **on its own** would already be enough to stream the TCP data to whatever process opens the /dev/ttyVA00 device. There is no need to create a pair of ptys, as the *entire point* of a pty is that software could directly attach to the "back end" of one. (Indeed that's what socat would do in the first command! It doesn't create a linked pair of ptys A–B; it's just A–socat and socat–B.)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the second command doesn't work by itself. With program 1 running, I can connect to it and monitor the stream of data sent with: "str2str -in tcpcli://127.0.0.1:1234". The second command does indeed connect with program 1 however, if I try to monitor the data with the command "str2str -in serial://ttyVA00", it prints: stream server start / stream server start error

Comment: Wouldn't the command "sudo socat TCP:localhost:1234 pty,link=/dev/ttyVA00,raw,echo=0" send data out of ttyVA00? I need something to simulate it coming in, as I understand it.

Comment: No; the program that creates a pty will receive its "master" file descriptor and will write through the opposite end, making it appear to all other programs that any data that socat writes to the pty "master" is being received through the pty "front" (i.e. normal file descriptors). Again, that's literally how your pty-to-socat-to-pty pipe works – so there would be no difference if one side was replaced with TCP; using the `pty` keyword for the other side still means socat would be writing to the "pty master" end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @user1686, you helped me solve it, as you noted my second command was overwriting the device rather than writing to it. A virtual pair was however necessary:

```
sudo socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttyVA00,echo=0,perm=0777 pty,link=/dev/ttyVB00,echo=0,perm=0777
```

The second command connects to Program 1 and forwards its data stream to ttyVA00 specifying the baud rate:

```
socat TCP:localhost:1234 /dev/ttyVA00,b115200,raw,echo=0
```

Now ttyVB00 is accessible with minicom, for example:

```
minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyVB00
```